# Trying to deploy strapi project to Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, strapi

I have a project which has been based on the top of this [tutorial](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-starter-next-js-blog).

I have been trying to deploy to Heroku following both:

1) [Strapi docs to deploy to Heroku](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/heroku.html#_2-login-to-heroku-from-your-cli)
2) [Install on Atlas: MongoDB Atlas](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html#mongodb-installation)

my prod database config is as follow:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "uri": "${process.env.DATABASE_URI}",
        "database": "${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}"
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "admin",
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

environment variables have been set in Heroku, when I try the prod environment locally it fails with the above config, if I replace the URI string I got from:

[image]

I manage to run prod database locally. 
Even when I `push heroku master` and the build is successful I get: https://alex-web-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

and the logs are:

[image]

Comment: You need to find the logs that show you the reason for "crashed", which may entail adding logging to your application or finding where it currently logs.

Comment: Can you please confirm you properly set the host to `0.0.0.0` in the `config/environments/*/server.json` and not to some domain or localhost?